# Import a CSV file using Databricks CLI in Repos

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-repos

We are using Databricks to generate ETL scripts. One step requires us to upload small csvs into a Repos folder. I can do this manually using the import window in the Repos GUI. However, i would like to do this programmatically using the databricks cli. Is this possible? I have tried using the Workspace API, but this only works for sourcecode files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible as of right now, because there is no API for that that could be used by databricks-cli. But you can add and commit files to the Git repository, and then use `databricks repos update` to pull them inside the workspace.